# Is it permissible for Muslim men to wear silver chains?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith

I would like to wear silver chain.

Is it permissible for Muslim men to wear silver chains?

If it is haram please give me a proof of it being so from hadith.

Comment: I think Shiite scholars allow wearing of silver chains if they are valid reasons for it, such as for carrying Islamic symbols or prayers for protection. So please specify which school of jurisprudence you want to answer your question.

Answer (score 6):

**I found these after a Google search:**

- [Verdict from IslamQA](http://islamqa.info/en/6697) : *With regard to wearing chains, this is not permissible for men, because this is an imitation of women, and there is no report which says that it is permissible for men to wear chains made of silver.*
- [Verdict from AskImam](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/19066) : *Wearing a silver chain, regardless of its size, is impermissible for men.*
- [Verdict from onIslam.net](http://www.onislam.net/english/ask-the-scholar/morals-and-manners/456495-could-a-man-wear-silver-chains.html) : *Generally speaking, it is not permissible for men to wear chains as this is considered an imitation to women ... if a man is required for health reasons to wear chains, he is then allowed to for such a necessity.*

---

<sup>All of the three are **Sunni** fatwa sites</sup>

Comment: The question is clearly asking for evidences from hadith.

Comment: @goldPseudo  I could only find these fatwas.

Answer (score 0):

The Hanafis, Malikis and some of the Shafi'is and Hanbalis do not consider it permissible for men to wear any silver jewelry unless there is explicit evidence to allow it. And the evidence for permission only exists for a silver ring or a decorated sword, or a replacement tooth\nose. Other jewelry is considered forbidden or makruh by them.

This is based on analogy with the ahadith:

> الذهب والفضة والحرير والديباج هي لهم في الدنيا، ولكم في الآخرة
>
> Gold, silver, silk and Dibaj (a kind of silk) are for them (unbelievers) in this world and for you (Muslims) in the hereafter.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5831)</sup>

> الذي يشرب في إناء الفضة إنما يجرجر في بطنه نار جهنم
>
> He who drinks in silver utensils is only filling his Abdomen with Hell Fire
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5634)</sup>

As silver jewelry is like silver utensils, and is part of what is meant for the Muslims in the hereafter ([Quran 76:21](https://quran.com/76/21?translations=20)). Hence by analogy it should be forbidden just like gold jewelry and silver utensils and silk.

Some also explicitly say that the same extends to jewelry of metals other than gold and silver based on the hadith of throwing away of the rings and even limitations on the silver rings:

> أن رجلا، جاء إلى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم وعليه خاتم من حديد فقال ‏‏ ما لي أرى عليك حلية أهل النار ‏‏ فطرحه ثم جاءه وعليه خاتم من شبه فقال ‏‏ ما لي أجد منك ريح الأصنام ‏‏ فطرحه قال يا رسول الله من أى شىء أتخذه قال ‏‏ من ورق ولا تتمه مثقالا ‏‏
>
> A man came to the Prophet [SAW] and he was wearing an iron ring. He said: "Why do I see you wearing the jewelry of the people of Hell?" He threw it away, then he came and he was wearing a brass ring. He said: "Why do I notice the stench of idols from you?" So he threw it away, and said: "O Messenger of Allah, what should I use?" He said: "Silver, but it should not equal a Mithqal."
>
> <sup>— [Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai:5195) etc.</sup>

When an iron and brass ring was forbidden then jewelry other than a ring is also forbidden. And silver jewelry (other than a ring) is also forbidden.

Further, wearing jewelry is something specific to women as evident from the Quran:

> ينشأ في الحلية
>
> one brought up in ornaments
>
> <sup>— [Quran 43:18](https://quran.com/43/18?translations=20)</sup>

And it is forbidden for men to imitate women in what is specific to them:

> لعن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم المتشبهين من الرجال بالنساء، والمتشبهات من النساء بالرجال
>
> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) cursed the women who imitate men and the men who imitate women.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5885)</sup>

**Ref:** https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/21424/

Answer (score -2):

Wearing of chain by male was never permissible at the time of the prophet. He only permitted wearing of silver ring and that was all. Don't be confused that because he permitted the wearing of silver rings has made wearing of silver chains halaal. Chains are objects for the beautification of the females not males. The fact is that chain was never permissible for male and it will never be.

Comment: Well, in the current day and age, wearing a silver chain is not associated with women. This being so, I think that that hadith does not apply to this situation.